# Why does zarr.convenince.consolidate_metadata() not work within a LinearFlow (metaflow)?

Tags: python, zarr, netflix-metaflow

This is an issue about [metaflow](/questions/tagged/metaflow), [zarr](/questions/tagged/zarr), [python](/questions/tagged/python)
I am creating a LinearFlow using metaflow and zarr.

All is going well except one key zarr function: when I try to [consolidate all my metadata into a Metadata Store](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/convenience.html) inside the flow, I get no error message but the metadata does not get consolidated (i.e. the Metadata Store does not get created)

any insight from the metaflow community or the zarr community as to why that is? Thanks a bunch !

This is the line of code that does nothing once put inside a LinearFlow:

```
metadata_store = zarr.convenience.consolidate_metadata(path_for_store, metadata_key=".all_metadata")
```